# How to create a widget that takes no space in MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween?

Tags: flutter, dart

If you have a `Row` in Flutter and set it to `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`, all Children gets evenly spaced by the distances between each other.

However, if you are conditionally displaying Widgets in this Row (`(boolean) ? Display : Container()`), the empty Container actually counts as a Widget that takes space with this particular mainAxisAlignment, and you will see empty space instead of Flutter just ignoring it completely and realigning as if it does not exist.

How do I keep using MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween and use a conditional empty Widget at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use

```
(boolean) ? Display : Container()
```

but simply

```
if (boolean) Display
```